# Converting a Variant to bool

Tags: boolean, c++builder, c++builder-10-seattle

How do you convert a Variant to bool in C++Builder 10?

In the old bcc32 compiler, I used the following code to check whether some generic TComponent was enabled:

```
if ((bool)GetPropValue(c, "Enabled", false))
    do_something();
```

However, after upgrading to C++Builder 10 and enabling the new Clang-based compiler, I get the following error:

```
[CLANG Error] VclHelpers.cpp(1375): ambiguous conversion for C-style cast from 'System::Variant' to 'bool'
```

The full compiler messages indicate that 36 of Variant's conversion operators are considered legal candidates: `operator double()`, `operator wchar_t*`, etc.

Comment: I have not been working with C++Builder, but an option ought to be to convert to int?

Comment: @user2672165 - Yes, that seems to work, although it seems inelegant.

Comment: @JoshKelley: Why are you even bothering with RTTI at all? The `TControl::Enabled` property is **public**, so you can do this instead: `if (c->Enabled) ...`. If you are going to use RTTI, then you might consider using `TRttiProperty::GetValue()` instead of `GetPropValue()`, as `TRttiProperty::GetValue()` returns a `TValue`, which has an `AsBoolean()` method. `TRttiContext ctx; if (ctx.GetType(c->ClassType())->GetProperty("Enabled")->GetValue(c).AsBoolean()) ...`

Comment: @JoshKelley: If you are going to use `GetPropValue()`, then maybe just get rid of the explicit type-cast at least.  Let the compiler figure out which conversion operator to call for you: `bool bEnabled = GetPropValue(c, "Enabled", false); if (bEnabled) ...`.  Otherwise, invoke the desired operator directly instead of using a type-cast: `if (GetPropValue(c, "Enabled", false).operator bool()) ...`

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Thanks. I oversimplified my code when posting; it's dealing with TComponent, not TControl. But you're right, since TControl::Enable is public and I mostly care about TControls, maybe I should just restructure the code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - `TRttiProperty` works (and I wasn't aware of that approach; thanks), as does explicitly invoking `.operator bool()`. Letting the compiler figure it out generates the same ambiguity errors (but only if I'm using the Clang-based compiler). Thanks for your help; if you want to post this as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: @JoshKelley: If you have a `TComponent*` and you want to check the `TControl::Enabled` property, simply type-cast to `TControl*` using `dynamic_cast` (in case the `TComponent*` is not pointing at a `TControl` descendant), eg: `TControl *ctrl = dynamic_cast<TControl*>(c); if ((ctrl) && (ctrl->Enabled)) ...`

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Yeah, I'm realizing now that I should have just done that. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `Variant` provides too many conversion operators. In particular, the following operators make conversion to bool ambiguous:

```
__fastcall operator bool() const;
__fastcall operator signed char*();
__fastcall operator unsigned char*();
// etc. - Variant has similar operators for short, int, long, float, double...
// It calls these "by ref" conversions.
```

As I understand it, non-const overloads are normally preferred to const overloads, but with >1 alternative for non-const convertible-to-bool pointer conversions as well as a const bool conversion, the conversion is ambiguous.

It's probably a mistake for `Variant` to have its conversions designed in such a way that they can't be used without ambiguity, but with help from @user2672165's and @Remy Lebeau's comments, there are several workarounds:

```
// Convert to int instead of bool.
if ((int)GetPropValue(c, "Enabled", false)) {}

// Make the Variant const, to avoid the ambiguous non-const conversions.
if (const_cast<const Variant>(GetPropValue(c, "Enabled", false))) {}

// Explicitly invoke the desired conversion operator.
if (GetPropValue(CheckBox1, "Enabled", false).operator bool()) {}

// Use TRttiProperty instead of Variant.
RttiContext ctx;
if (ctx.GetType(c->ClassType())->GetProperty("Enabled")->GetValue(c).AsBoolean()) {}
```